# what does p is undefined means in jquery.dataTables.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatable, angular-datatables

I'm getting this error in console when I try to render a dataTable using angular with ECMAScript 5 for project circumnstances (nothing I can do about it).

ERROR TypeError: p is undefined

I read like 1000 questions similar to this one and the number of tr in my table equals the number of th, and there are no colspan tags or any other not supported feature in the table, in fact, it couldn't be simpler... In this project, also, there are other dataTables which are working fine with the same structure. I already lost three days trying to figure this out, but no luck. Please, please, please, I could use some help from the community.

```
getCurationsList(){
    this.commonService.getCurations().subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result[0]) {
          this.curation.curations = result[1];
          this.globals.tableCurationVisible = false;
          
            setTimeout(() => {
              const table = $('#dataTableCurations').DataTable({
                /*Ordering by date */
                // autoWidth: false,
                deferRender: true,
                ordering: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                columnDefs: [{ 'type': 'date-euro', 'targets': 2 }],
                order: [[1, 'desc']],
                destroy: true
              });

              if (this.curation.curations.length > 0) {
                this.curation.name = $('#dataTableCurations tbody tr:first td:first').text();
              for(let i=0; i<this.curation.curations.length;i++){
                  console.log(this.curation.curations[i]);
                  let icur = this.curation.curations[i];
                  this.curation.name = icur['curation_endpoint'];
                  this.curation.date = icur['creation_date'];
              }
                    }
              this.globals.tableCurationVisible = true;
            }, 10);
          } 
          else {
            alert(result[1]);
          }
        },
        error => {
          alert(error.message);
        }
    )
  }

}
```

The values are correctly stored/rescued from the response in this.curation.curations, and I can access them from the component.ts, in fact if I place any other id value for the table, which is not dataTable, I have a perfect table with all the stuff in the right order and place, but the project requires me to use dataTables.

Here the html:

```
 <table id="dataTableCurations" class="table" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 12%">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 12%">Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of this.curation.curations" (click)= "selectCuration(item['curation_endpoint'], item['creation_date'])" [ngClass]="{'selected': this.curation.name===item['curation_endpoint']}">
              <td>{{item['curation_endpoint']}}</td>
              <td>{{item['creation_date']}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: *p is undefined* sounds like a variable that is called but not defined - but there is none in your posted code - could you please post the whole error message with line number etc.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: p is undefined
    jQuery 13
    getCurationsList common.functions.ts:345//this line = const table... in the above code
    Angular 16
    getCurationsList common.functions.ts:344
    RxJS 14
    Angular 16
    RxJS 8
    Angular 10

Comment: and there's no p being called from my side, maybe jQuery datatables requires this, but I'm not finding any reference to it. thanks for reviewing, anyway.

Comment: To get a more verbose message, change the minimized JS resources for unminimized ones. That way, the variable names you see may be more meaningful (or, at least, they will be less... minimized).

Comment: Having said that, this error can happen when you have a mismatch between the number of columns defined in your HTML and the number of columns expected by DataTables. In your case, your HTML has 2 columns (name and date), but the `columnDefs` only refers to 1 column - and even worse, its index is `2` - which means "the third column", since col indexes are zero-based. I would start there.

Comment: Thankyou @andrewjames!!!! This solved the issue and everything is working just fine. Thank  you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you andrewjames. The issue was in the ColumnDefs which is zero based, so the number of columns must also start in 0. changing this worked:

```
columnDefs: [{ 'type': 'date-euro', 'targets': 1 }],//because there are two columns
```